# i dont know anything in physics but what i know is number system now explain me why we need unit and dimensions and what exactly are they?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units

imagine I just know number system nothing else I want to intuitively understand development of units and dimension with **very very clear** definition of both of them what exactly is a unit how is it different from dimension don't use difficult words

Comment: possibly interesting, if you have a background in mathematics: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

Comment: Wikipedia has pages on both "dimension" and "unit of measurement" which should explain everything.

Comment: @Andrew What the mathematicians are missing there, I think, is that physicist are actually not all that interested in units. We are mostly interested in scaling laws, i.e. how a phenomenon depends on other phenomena and which phenomenon dominates at a certain scale. This is how we are building multidimensional maps of the world that allow us to identify what is important and what isn't. Units are, more or less, just a pedantic accounting tool.

Comment: if you people didnt had answer why did you close it if someone knew he would have replied this is not the answer that scientists are not interested i dont care who is interested or not but this was my genuine question

Comment: @MohitBhaker I gave you one of many answers and I didn't vote to close it. You have an interesting question about the basics of physics. It has many facets, though. I only gave you one of the most trivial ones. Maybe that is not what you were trying to ask about? If that's the case, please follow the advice of the moderator who closed the question and try to be more specific about what aspect of this you are interested in. We will try to help you. Peace!

Comment: i am sorry @FlatterMann if i was rude

Comment: hey @FlatterMann i was just angry at folks who closed the question i actually dont know who is doing that

Comment: @MohitBhaker You sounded a little frustrated. Frustration is part of the scientific method. Nature (textbooks, other scientists) are often not able to give us perfect answers. Sometimes answers come in tiny portions over very long stretches of time (centuries, actually). Sometimes what is important about a question and answers is not what you had in mind initially. Other people can give you new dimensions to a problem that you may not have been thinking about, yet. The more colorful the answers, the more likely it is that you are learning something new.

Comment: @FlatterMann yess i was frustrated i just wanted to knew answer i thought that i will wait for an hour then i will get the answer but the question got closed that was frustating

Comment: @Andrew thanks it was very interesting

Comment: I think the reason why your question is closed is because it really reads as a "I dont want to do the work to read up on stuff, just explain as if I am a king". There are quite some mathematical expositions on units and dimensions for you to read online if you just searched a bit. And then you can phrase the question better, showing what you have digested of the reading you do.

Comment: What is 5 inches + 3 seconds?

Comment: @SolomonSlow If you can't add them, it's an affine space.

Answer (score 4):

In physics, we're not really interested in very, very clear definitions, but in answers to real world questions like "how far away is the Sun". So, we use words *pragmatically*, not precisely (making mathematicians crazy). So, start from what it is you want to measure. How do you do it? How do you express the result?

Comment: if you people didnt had answer why did you close it if someone knew he would have replied this is not the answer that scientists are not interested i dont care who is interested or not but this was my genuine question

Comment: @MohitBhaker John Doty was trying to make an interesting point. Physics is, indeed "pragmatic". It is very, very far removed from mathematics, even if it (ab)uses the language of mathematics for its purposes. I may not agree with John completely on just how "pragmatic" we are, because a lot of the basic definitions in physics are actually pedantic at the level of lawyering, but he still made a very good point. Physical quantities are also about experimental procedure. When physicists are talking to each other they usually have some way in mind "how" one can actually measure something.

Comment: yeah i am sorry you are right he made a good point

Answer (score 3):

In physics every formula is an expression of complex physical phenomenon in multiples (and fractions) of simple physical phenomena. A simple phenomenon would be the existence of a yard stick, or a meter stick, if we work in SI units. So what "5m" means is that the length we are measuring is equivalent to placing five 1m base unit sticks next to each other. "165s" literally means that we are counting out 165 one second time intervals. So, yes, the number is "just" a count and the "unit" tells us what it is that we are counting.